# Elasticsearch+PHP: Array to string conversion error?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, indexing, mapping

Here's the basic structure of index 'test'

```
  PUT /test
    PUT /test/person/_mapping
    {
        "person" : {
            "properties" : {
                "my_attachment" : { "type" : "attachment" }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to index Word files from a folder called 'yellow' into my ES db.
My code in PHP:

```
<?php
$dir_path="yellow";
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$client= Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();
if(is_dir($dir_path))
{
    $files=opendir($dir_path);
    if($files)
    {
        while(($file_name= readdir($files))!== FALSE)
        {
            if($file_name!=="."&$file_name!=="..")
            {
    $params = [
    'index' => 'test',
    'type' => 'person',
    'body' => ['my_attachment' => base64_encode(file_get_contents("$dir_path/$file_name")) ]
];
$response= $client->index($params);
echo $response;
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I'm getting the error

> Notice: Array to String conversion on line 20

Which is the line "echo $response;" of my code.

Comment: What if you use `print_r` instead of `echo`?

Comment: It worked. Thanks! Such a simple error, amazing how I spent so much time on this.